# C Programming fatal error my sql.h no file or such directory on code blocks

Tags: mysql, c

I'm unable to use mysql on C when I do #include <mysql.h> or #include "mysql.h". Every time I try to run this program, I get a fatal error.

I put these as my linker settings to add the sql library :
C:\Program Files\MySQL\Connector C++ 8.0\libmysqlclient.so
C:\Program Files\MySQL\MySQL Server 8.0

also this is my search directories:
C:\Program Files\MySQL\Connector C++ 8.0
C:\Program Files\MySQL\MySQL Server 8.0

Any idea how to make codeblocks work with this?

Thanks and I'll keep searching too.

Comment: In looking for the answer, I found it.

So instead of doing what I did in the link and search directories, instead do this:

Linker settings:
"C:\Program Files\MySQL\MySQL Server 8.0\lib\libmysql.lib"
"C:\Program Files\MySQL\MySQL Server 8.0\lib\mysqlclient.lib"

Search Directores:
"C:\Program Files\MySQL\MySQL Server 8.0\lib"
"C:\Program Files\MySQL\MySQL Server 8.0\include"

This allowed me to compile the code with no errors .

Answer (score 0):

In looking for the answer, I found it. So instead of doing what I did in the link and search directories, instead do this:
Linker settings:
"C:\Program Files\MySQL\MySQL Server 8.0\lib\libmysql.lib"
"C:\Program Files\MySQL\MySQL Server 8.0\lib\mysqlclient.lib"

Search Directores:
"C:\Program Files\MySQL\MySQL Server 8.0\lib"
"C:\Program Files\MySQL\MySQL Server 8.0\include"
This allowed me to compile the code with no errors